# How to ignore packages in emma code coverage for android?

Tags: android, jenkins, emma

I've got a project set up like this:

- MyLibrary (library code used by other projects)
- MyLibraryTest (unit tests for MyLibrary)
- MyService (the application, references MyLibrary in project.properties)
- MyServiceTest (unit tests for MyLibrary)

I want to generate code coverage reports for MyLibrary and MyService, which I can do. However, the report for MyServiceTest includes the packages in MyLibrary (which aren't tested, so shouldn't be there). Likewise, the report for MyLibraryTest shows MyService's coverage because MyService is the instrumented application.

I can add `<property name="emma.filter" value="-com.my.library.package.*" />` to the build.xml of MyLibrary and that blocks those lines from showing in MyServiceTest's report. Unfortunately it also blocks the lines in MyLibraryTest.

How can I set up the build.xml filters so that only the packages in the library are shown in MyLibraryTest's emma reports, and only the packages for MyService show up in the MyServiceTest's report?